# How to integrate Azure Voice API in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

Now I am integrating Azure Voice API in my MERN stack project.
I tested it in console with debugging but it doesn't work on React Website.

I am not sure what's the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Azure Voice Api, You need to get the authorize from the Azure Support team.
If you didn't get it, you can't call it in website.
Please check your debug console, you can get the Azure support link.
And then fill in the require field and submit it to the support team.

Comment: If you send the document with company name and other info, they will contact you and let you know the result. It will take at least 15 days.

Answer (score 3):

#### Install the Speech SDK

```
const sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
```

#### Create a speech configuration

```
const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("<paste-your-speech-key-here>", "<paste-your-speech-location/region-here>");
```

There are a few other ways that you can initialize a [SpeechConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechconfig)

#### Recognize from file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("<paste-your-speech-key-here>", "<paste-your-speech-location/region-here>");

function fromFile() {
    let audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(fs.readFileSync("YourAudioFile.wav"));
    let recognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

    recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(result => {
        console.log(`RECOGNIZED: Text=${result.text}`);
        recognizer.close();
    });
}
fromFile();
```

#### Recognize from in-memory stream

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("<paste-your-speech-key-here>", "<paste-your-speech-location/region-here>");

function fromStream() {
    let pushStream = sdk.AudioInputStream.createPushStream();

    fs.createReadStream("YourAudioFile.wav").on('data', function(arrayBuffer) {
        pushStream.write(arrayBuffer.slice());
    }).on('end', function() {
        pushStream.close();
    });
 
    let audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(pushStream);
    let recognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(result => {
        console.log(`RECOGNIZED: Text=${result.text}`);
        recognizer.close();
    });
}
fromStream();
```

#### Error handling

```
switch (result.reason) {
    case sdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        console.log(`RECOGNIZED: Text=${result.text}`);
        break;
    case sdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
        console.log("NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
        break;
    case sdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        const cancellation = CancellationDetails.fromResult(result);
        console.log(`CANCELED: Reason=${cancellation.reason}`);

        if (cancellation.reason == sdk.CancellationReason.Error) {
            console.log(`CANCELED: ErrorCode=${cancellation.ErrorCode}`);
            console.log(`CANCELED: ErrorDetails=${cancellation.errorDetails}`);
            console.log("CANCELED: Did you update the key and location/region info?");
        }
        break;
    }
```

#### Continuous recognition

Start by defining the input and initializing a [SpeechRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechrecognizer):

```
const recognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
```

Next, subscribe to the events sent from the [SpeechRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechrecognizer).

```
recognizer.recognizing = (s, e) => {
    console.log(`RECOGNIZING: Text=${e.result.text}`);
};

recognizer.recognized = (s, e) => {
    if (e.result.reason == sdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
        console.log(`RECOGNIZED: Text=${e.result.text}`);
    }
    else if (e.result.reason == sdk.ResultReason.NoMatch) {
        console.log("NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
    }
};

recognizer.canceled = (s, e) => {
    console.log(`CANCELED: Reason=${e.reason}`);

    if (e.reason == sdk.CancellationReason.Error) {
        console.log(`"CANCELED: ErrorCode=${e.errorCode}`);
        console.log(`"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=${e.errorDetails}`);
        console.log("CANCELED: Did you update the key and location/region info?");
    }

    recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
};

recognizer.sessionStopped = (s, e) => {
    console.log("\n    Session stopped event.");
    recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
};
```

With everything set up, call [startContinuousRecognitionAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechrecognizer#startcontinuousrecognitionasync) to start recognizing.

```
recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();

// make the following call at some point to stop recognition.
// recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
```

#### Dictation mode

```
speechConfig.enableDictation();
```

#### Change source language

```
speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "it-IT";
```

#### Improve recognition accuracy

```
const phraseList = sdk.PhraseListGrammar.fromRecognizer(recognizer);
phraseList.addPhrase("Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious");
```

If you need to clear your phrase list:

```
phraseList.clear();
```

For more details [here...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-nodejs)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I checked the code you wrote, but I have already improved this feature in my project, I think the problem is another thing.
I checked @metaman 's answer and it is correct in my case.

Answer (score 2):

It's the way I found.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("<paste-your-speech-key-here>", "<paste-your-speech-location/region-here>");

function fromStream() {
    let pushStream = sdk.AudioInputStream.createPushStream();

    fs.createReadStream("YourAudioFile.wav").on('data', function(arrayBuffer) {
        pushStream.write(arrayBuffer.slice());
    }).on('end', function() {
        pushStream.close();
    });
 
    let audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(pushStream);
    let recognizer = new sdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(result => {
        console.log(`RECOGNIZED: Text=${result.text}`);
        recognizer.close();
    });
}
fromStream();
```